# Importing Data from Text File to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a tab-delimited text file called Log.txt that I write to using a macro. Here are the contents of the text file:

```
"test1  test1   test1   test1   test1   test1   test1   test1   test1   test1   test1   test1   test1   test1   test1   test1   test1   test1"
"test2  test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   test2   test2"
"test3  test3   test3   test3   test3   test3   test3   test3   test3   test3   test3   test3   test3   test3   test3   test3   test3   test3"
"test4  test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4"
```

I'd like to write each line of the text file (4 lines currently, but will expand with time) to a sheet called "Log" in my spreadsheet, starting at cell B2. Each line has 18 cells worth of data. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Refresh_Log()
Dim Str As String, FileNum As Integer, FileName As String, Arr() As String
FileNum = FreeFile()
FileName = "P:/Log.txt"
ReDim Arr(17, 0)
Open FileName For Input As #FileNum
While Not EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, Str
    For i = 0 To 17
        Arr(i, UBound(Arr, 2)) = Split(Str, Chr(9))(i)
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve Arr(17, UBound(Arr, 2) + 1)
Wend
Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Any tips on how to alter the code to make it write the data from Log.txt into the Log sheet, line by line, starting at cell B2? I don't want it to include the quotation marks at the beginning and end of each line. For example, the first line ("test1...") will go into row 2 starting at column B (B2), second line will go into row 3 starting at column B (B3), third line into row 4 column B, etc.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the "get and transform" built in options?

Comment: Have you considered using a Power Query? Data->Get Data->Launch Power Query editor. From there you can New Source->File->Text. Then there are plenty of baked in tools to massage the data to be how you want it. (more advanced stuff also available in 'advanced editor' but there is a learning curve). Then click "close and load" and boom! it is in your workbook. You can refresh the query whenever you want. Data->Refresh All.

Comment: I've never used Power Query before. But I figured out how to do it with VBA!

Comment: Power query is an interesting tool. I came across it because I needed to 'unpivot' data. It's a nice little tool that gives normal users a few more tricks to use before bringing out the big guns. I think it is worth having a basic familiarity with, if you use excel a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is write the array to the sheet range like this:

```
With Sheets("Log")
    .Range("B2").Resize(UBound(Arr, 1) - LBound(Arr, 1) + 1, UBound(Arr, 2) - LBound(Arr, 2) + 1).Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Arr)
End With
```

Comment: This is really close! The only thing is it pastes the data vertically instead of horizontally. In other words, It pastes the 18 values for the first line in column B, 18 values for second line in column C, etc. whereas it should paste the 18 values for the first line in B2 to S2 (18 cell range), second line in B3 to S3, etc. Also, is there a way to get rid of the " " at the beginning/end of each line?

Comment: Changing = Arr to = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Arr) did it for me, thanks for the help!

Comment: @hasingh – Perfect, I've edited my answer to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna import the file you can do it this way:

```
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & Filename, Destination:=Range("$B$2"))
    .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "log"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 1257
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```